# Check Lithium Related Side Effects Without Blood Test

Tags: mental-health, treatment, blood-tests, renal, lithium

**Situation:**

- A middle aged patient with no health insurance and a well documented
  history of moderate to severe bipolar disorder visits a low cost clinic.
- The patient has a just lapsed lithium prescription and cannot get a 
  refill directly at a pharmacy.  The patient needs a new prescription 
  for lithium, and this is the reason for the visit.
- The health care provider would like to draw blood to test renal function.
- Unfortunately, lab tests are not provided free, and the cost of the blood test is outside of the reach of the patient.  A urine test is also too expensive.
- There is more than one patient with this situation.

**Question:**

*Is there an alternative method(without lab tests) that can assess whether the prescription can be safely filled?*

Assume there is one doctor/physician assistant/nurse practitioner donating time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Blood tests to determine lithium levels are the gold standard for assessing the efficacy of lithium therapy. That said, a patient on a stable dose with no major adverse reactions is presumably within their body's therapeutic range. If there is preexisting renal dysfunction, that brings in a whole new can of worms. The signs and symptoms of lithium overdose are well documented and easily researched. I see many similar scenarios with metformin. Renal function should always to tested periodically throughout treatment but is rarely performed. I say that to say this, if the patient is tolerating the medication, isn't showing signs of renal dysfunction, and has no major reactions, I think it should be OK to prescribe/dispense the medication while diligently monitoring the patient for and changes.

Comment: Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that **all answers** should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].

Comment: Hmm I have gathered that by the time you start experiencing major side effects it is to quite late in your kidney failing.